# join two data frame with different row

Tags: r

I have two data frames with different row numbers but corresponds to same ID .

```
df1 <- 
        ID      Day                            sign
1       1       -3                            positive
2       1       -2                            positive
3       1       -1                            positive
4       1        0                            positive
5       1        1                            positive
6       2       -4                            positive
7       2       -3                            positive
8       2       -2                            positive
9       2       -1                            ULD
10      2        0                            ULD
11      3       -2                            positive
12      3       -1                            positive
13      3        0                            positive
14      3        1                            positive
..      ..         ..        .....                       .....
```

df2<-

```
       ID         Type
1       1        secondary
2       1        secondary
3       2        primary
4       2        primary
5       3        secondary
6       3        secondary
```

I would like to add a column in df1 called "Type" whose entries (for each StudyNo) corresponds to the "Type" given in df2. In particular I would like the result to be:

```
df1 <- 
        ID      Day                            sign        Type
1       1       -3                            positive     secondary
2       1       -2                            positive      secondary
3       1       -1                            positive      secondary
4       1        0                            positive      secondary
5       1        1                            positive      secondary
6       2       -4                            positive      primary
7       2       -3                            positive      primary
8       2       -2                            positive       primary
9       2       -1                            ULD            primary
10      2        0                            ULD            primary
11      3       -2                            positive       secondary
12      3       -1                            positive       secondary
13      3        0                            positive       secondary
14      3        1                            positive       secondary
..      ..         ..        .....                       .....
```

I am using dplyr and have tried

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by ="ID")
```

but the resulting table has repeated entries: eg. 10 entries for ID=1. 
Any help in getting the desired output as in df3 is appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason why `df2` has multiple rows per ID? If each ID only has one type, you can probably do `df3 <- left_join(df1, distinct(df2), by ="ID")`

Comment: df3 has many other columns with specific values corresponding to each ID . The answer by @Marius did do what I wanted